# no response when using psql createdb

Tags: postgresql, passwords, infinite-loop, psql

I am trying to create a database using the createdb function in psql.

```
createdb -U postgres testdb
```

When using the command about, it seems like it hits an infinite loop. No errors and no response until i press ctrl+c.
[psql createdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpuSD.png)

There is a password on the "postgres" user. To avoid typing it, I tried to force no password, but that returns the error, that the password is incorrect

```
createdb -U postgres -w testdb
```

I use version 13.2.

Comment: Check for locks in `pg_locks`.

Comment: I did the following, but not really sure how to read it? https://imgur.com/a/Tzv0diH

Comment: @Jooks  That looks like the pg_locks from a completely idle server with no connections other than the one inspecting pg_locks.  Did you run that during the time the createdb was trying to run?